# How to run a js/jquery function only after the page's content is reloaded with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table with pagination. The pagination uses ajax - when i click on a second page link, it fires js function LoadPage() which reloads the page content. I also use some jquery script to modify the table code after the page is loaded:

```
function addNames() {
        $('.Table tr)').each(function () { 
   $(this).attr('name', ''); // adding empty name attribte to each row of table
});
        console.log('names are applied');
    }
    
    
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        addNames();
});
```

The problem is that this code (that adds the attribute) works only on a first page. When the page 2 or more is loaded, it does not work at all. Maybe the approach could be to add addNames() into the LoadPage() (after ajax is completed), but i can't do this cuase this function is not allowed to be edited, cause it is generated by my codegenerator program.

I tried to fire the addNames() when clicking the page 2/3/... link element (it has class ".PageLinkClass"), with this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.PageLinkClass').on('click', function() { 
            addNames();
        });
        });
```

but it does not solve my problem cause it runs before the ajax reload is fully completed. So what can i do with this, how can i make addNames() fire only after page is fully reload?